# How to check yaml Schema in multiple levels using Python

Tags: python, pyyaml

If the yaml file is valid, the method `yaml.safe_load()` will convert the file to a dictionary (in the code is represented by the variable `CONFIG`).

After the first validation, it should check each key to see if the type matches.

```
from schema import Use, Schema, SchemaError
import yaml

config_schema = Schema(
    {
        "pipeline": Use(
            str,
            error="Unsupported pipeline name. A string input is expected"
        ),
        "retry_parameters": Use(
            int,
            error="Unsupported retry strategy. An integer input is expected"
        )
    },
    error="A yaml file is expected"
)

CONFIG = """
pipeline: 1
retry_parameters: 'pipe_1'
"""

configuration = yaml.safe_load(CONFIG)

try:
    config_schema.validate(configuration)
    print("Configuration is valid.")
except SchemaError as se:
    for error in se.errors:
        if error:
            print(error)
```

In the example above, it's raising and printing three errors.

```
A yaml file is expected
A yaml file is expected
Unsupported retry strategy. A integer input is expected
```

But in that case I was expecting the following:

```
Unsupported pipeline name. A string input is expected
Unsupported retry strategy. A integer input is expected
```

How can I check if the file has a valid yaml format and after that check if each key has the expected type?

Comment: Schema library is of alpha quality and development ceased in 2021.
I suggest to use **Pydantic 2** instead, which has the added benefit of Jsonschema compatibility. Or if you want more lightweight, **msgspec**, which also provides validation in a proprietary scheme like "Schema".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem using library Schema.

1. Firstly, in **Use** the argument indicates the data type to which the value must be converted. Since *1* is easily converted to *'1'*, you don't get the first error message. Accordingly, *'pipe_1'* cannot be converted to an *int*, and this exception appears. To fix this, change **Use** to **And**.
2. Secondly, since the block is **try/exept**, the first exception is caught, so the second error is not displayed. The first two errors are likely raised by any errors in the first argument (dictionary) of the Schema class. To output all errors, I think it is necessary to check line by line and save the errors.